# Cycles in NavigationController - how to avoid memory leaks?

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks, uinavigationcontroller

In my app I have a navigation controller with four controllers. The user navigate from `A -> B -> C -> D -> A_1 -> B_2 ->` ... etc. It's one way and every `ViewController` is always a new `ViewController`.

This cycle is intended. But in `ViewController A` and `C` I initialize `GoogleMaps` which is using a lot of memory. So after 15 loops (and 30 inits of GoogleMaps) my app crashes because of a memory leak.

Now I see different possibilities to solve this problem.

1) I do not init a new ViewController rather I reuse my VCs. So Google Maps just initialize two times. 
*I dislike this, because my VCs could have different states. A clean init would be more comfortable and a smaller source of errors*

2) I remove the stack at the right time, because the navigation is just one way. When the transition from `A -> B` is done I could throw A away. Same thing for `C -> D`.

3) I deinit Google Maps after transitions. I don't know how to do this yet but I'm quite sure that I will figure it out.

I read about [setViewControllers](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/1621861-setviewcontrollers) by which I can replace view controllers.

What is the best practice? What recomments Apple?

Comment: Also you can prevent repeated navigation from one VC to another.
I think it's the best way if it is possible.

Comment: This does not help. I need this cycle for the user experience. And when I will go back from D -> A without using a new vc I have the problem from 1)

Comment: I found use as many as "unowned"  as possible. So you can control from the design time.

Comment: Why `unowned`? Why not `weak`? And what would you exactly mark as `unowned`?

Comment: It reminds me they are class. BTW, if there is only one strong refer, it can be easier to manage.

Answer (score 0):

**Start with the 3rd and the easiest option:**

Use `override func viewWillDisappear(){}` to deinit google maps. You could use this method for 2nd option as well.

But I think, you should use delegates when you go back to A from D. What do you change on A, when you reach it again?

Comment: Hi, I would prefer `segues` or `unwind segues` than delegates at this point. When I leave from `A -> B` I have to reset all UI changes the user did in A. 
When I go from `D -> A` in the happy flow is that I show the init state + a message in a view. 

The controller will be get more features in future. So when I reuse the VC my fear is that I could make mistakes and the user will see wrong UI or have wrong states.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that navigation is just one way. If so you can just replace `UINavigationController`'s `viewControllers` array. In other words, you may not need navigation stack if a user does not go backward in the stack.

Alternatively, I got a similar issue in my app. When I am pushing a controller in the  `UINavigationController` it checks the existing `viewControllers` and modifies it. For example, if an identical controller is already there, pop to that copy.

Answer (score 0):

You can navigate view controllers from A -> B -> C -> D -> A_1 -> B_2 -> ... etc. using two method.

**Method 1:**
When you are going to D controller then pop to a specific controller(A controller) and again navigate cycle A to D with the push view controller.

```
self.navigationController?.popToViewController(A, animated: true)
```

**Method 2:** 
When you are going to D controller then the present controller (A controller) and dismiss presented cycle flow when you again reached at D controller

```
viewController.present(A, animated:true, completion: nil)
```